# Как сделать сноски в виде звёздочек Word?

Tags: ms-word

Как сделать сноски как в книжке в порядке: *(одна звездочка), **(две звездочки), ***(три звездочки) и т.д.
В Word по умолчанию стоит непонятный список сносок, где вторая по порядку сноска это какой то символ креста. Как сделать чтобы были только звездочки с увеличением их числа?

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в поле "другой" на скриншоте поставил звёздочку.

Comment: Попробуйте провести эту операцию. Не получается все равно